# MS Access displays alle columns in SQL Server tables as "deleted"

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, sql-server, odbc

I have created an ODBC connection to a SQL Server 2005.

When I link to the tables from MS Access, some tables have only "deleted" data.

This means the rows and columns are displayed, but all data seems "deleted" ("Geloscht" in the image)

I find it remarkable that some of the tables of the same database work fine.

[image]

Comment: This question deserves a +1 as well because this is a common occurence that @Stan the Man pointed out. All Access VBA developers should concur with this, and all others should be made aware of this by means of your question.

Comment: @jcolebrand: I would expect the content of the cells instead of the word "deleted". There is no such thing as "deleted" cells involced in the setup. Either tabel rows are or they are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the linked SQL Server table does not have a unique index on in. MS Access uses the MS Jet DB engine that is designed around a keyset model. Actions like inserts, updates, etc, uses this keyset. This may be missing from your linked SQL Server table. [Click here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128809) for more detailed info.

Comment: @mit I have seen this too in my developer days. This one hits the nail on the head !!! +1 for Stan the Man !!!

Comment: thank you, I was already suspecting it got something to do with unique indexes. When i linked the tables MS Access asked me about unique indexes. I will follow your link.